# Ayuda con trigger insert

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

Soy nueva en SQL y quiero hacer una pagina como de nuevo registro de usuarios, y que esta informacion se almacene en una tabla, (esta parte ya la tengo)
El problema, es que al momento de crear un nuevo usuario, tengo 2 tablas, una de empresas y otra de usuarios, entonces.. al momento de dar clic en el boton de guardar usuario o crear usuario, el mismo ID del usuario de la tabla de usuarios tiene que ser el mismo ID de usuario de la tabla de empresa.
El trigger que actualmente tengo me crea 2 filas, una con la informacion que necesito en las columnas que necesito a excepcion del ID, la otra linea de registro me deja todas las columnas null, y el ID lo registra.

Como puedo hacerle para que se registre el mismo ID en una sola linea?

este es el trigger que tengo actualmente:

```
create or replace trigger compania_trigger
   before insert or update on usuarios
   for each row



   begin
      if inserting then
         if :new.compania_id is null then
           select to_number(sys_guid(),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
           into :new.compania_id
           from dual;
         end if;
         :new.created    := sysdate;

      end if;

      if inserting or updating then
         :new.updated    := sysdate;

      end if;

   insert into empresas(compania_id) values (:new.compania_id);

end;
```

Comment: Comparte tu trigger

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. También a leer [ask] y finalmente a que edites tu pregunta e incluyas como mínimo el código relevante de tu trigger y las columnas relevantes de ambas tablas pues será más fácil entender que problema estás teniendo al ver el código y con eso aumentarán tus probabilidades de obtener ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: Listo, ya compartí el trigger

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si definis una variable dentro del trigger? similar a este codigo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON orders
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN

   -- Find username of person performing UPDATE on the table
   SELECT user INTO v_username
   FROM dual;

   -- Update updated_date field to current system date
   :new.updated_date := sysdate;

   -- Update updated_by field to the username of the person performing the UPDATE
   :new.updated_by := v_username;

END;
```

Y en vez de hacer

```
SELECT user INTO v_username
```

tenes que hacer:

```
select sys_guid() INTO  from dual
```

y tu variable la declaras asi:

```
DECLARE
uid raw(16)
```

Comment: Gracias! pero esa sería solo para cambiar el ID del user, en mi caso el valor compania_id tiene que ser insertado tanto en la tabla usuarios y en empresas al momento de crear nuevo registro

Comment: No puedes insertar un nuevo registro usando ese Guid, y luego colocarlo en el insert de la otra tabla?
Otra cosa, cuál es la tabla maestra? y cual es la que recibe como clave foránea ese id?

Comment: La que recibe la llave foranea es empresas, la tabla con la pk es usuarios

Comment: Y que tal si haces un trigger que se ejecute despues?
`create or replace trigger compania_trigger
   after insert`

Comment: Hacer lo de esta manera:

`create or replace trigger compania_trigger
 AFTER INSERT ON usuarios FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

 insert into empresas(usuario_id) values (:new.id);

END;`